# Relating the total number of divisors to a number being a perfect power.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

There is the following simple characterization of integer squares: an integer $n$ is a square if and only if $d(n)$, the total number of divisors of $n$, including $1$ and $n$, is odd. This follows immediately from the prime factorisation $n = p_1^{k_1} \dots p_r^{k_r}$ and the formula $d(n) = (k_1 + 1)(k_2 + 1) \dots (k_r + 1)$.

I was wondering if there were similar results for higher powers. To characterize when $x$ is a perfect $k$th power it is enough to know the case of $k$ being prime, since then for a composite number we can apply these tests iteratively. With this in mind, I tried to work with the cubic case, but couldn't find a satisfying result.

For instance, if $n = m^3$ then we can see $d(n) \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $\Omega(n) \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$, where $\Omega$ counts the prime factors with multiplicity. However, an integer satisfying these need not be a cube. Consider $p_1, \dots, p_{6}$ distinct primes then $n = p_1 \dots p_{6}$, or $n = p_1^4 \dots p_{6}^4$ satisfy these conditions. I tried to throw in additional conditions, but have not been able to figure it out. Any ideas?

Clarification: By ``simple" I suppose I want us to assume that we do not have direct access to the multiplicities of the primes dividing n. Otherwise (as Lee Mosher points out) we can check these modulo 3. I think it should be okay to have access to values of common arithmetic functions, as we do in the square result.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are asking. One very simple criterion that $n$ be a cube is simply that each exponent is divisible by $3$, but presumably you know that criterion and it is not acceptable to you as being "simple". If so then it would clarify your post if you could explain something about what criteria would be acceptable to you.

Comment: @LeeMosher You're right, I've added some clarification. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: $8$ has $4$ factors. So does $10$. But $8$ is a perfect cube and $10$ is not. So you cannot just look at the number of factors. What other information about factors do you consider to be “simple”?

Comment: @DavidK I was hoping for something that only had to with basic arithmetic functions like $d(n)$, $\Omega(n)$, $\omega(n)$, or $\sigma(n)$. As well as imposing some congruences.

Comment: After mistakenly going down some dead ends: There are cubes with every number of divisors equivalent to $1$ modulo $3$. But as @DavidK has pointed out, this is not sufficient to guarantee a cube.

Comment: You can find some more criteria in this short preprint of mine concerning perfect cubes in the OEIS sequence A352991 (see Corollary 2 and Remark 1): https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.10163.pdf

Comment: "To characterize when $x$ is a perfect $k$th power it is enough to know the case of $k$ being prime, since then for a composite number we can apply these tests iteratively."—This only works for squarefree exponents. (How can we use a yes-no test for cubes to construct a test for $9$th powers, for example?)

Comment: Moreover, I quote the observation that $d(n) \equiv 1\pmod 3$ is a necessary but not sufficient condition. Thus, the original question should be edited properly, IMHO.

Comment: My best guess at the question being asked is: is there any system of congruences $d(n)\equiv a\pmod b$, $\Omega(n)\equiv c\pmod e$, $\omega(n)\equiv f\pmod g$, $\sigma(n)\equiv h\pmod j$ that give necessary and sufficient conditions for $n$ to be a cube? I actually doubt that there's such a system that gives sufficient conditions, let alone necessary and sufficient.

Comment: @GregMartin A number n is a 9th power iff it is a cube and its cubed root is a cube.

Comment: But a yes-no test for cubeness doesn't produce a cube root to test for its own cubeness. And if we're willing to take (cube) roots, then determining whether integers are perfect powers is trivial anyway.

Comment: @GregMartin I suppose what I am allowing is for us to take roots when we know the root is an integer.

Comment: The same algorithm that determines the cube root of an integer known to be a cube will also determine whether it's a cube in the first place. Anyway, you can set whatever rules you want (although it's better to set them in the post itself rather than in comments), but I think even the original $d(n)$-is-odd characterization is mostly for fun: in practice, it's far harder to compute $d(n)$ (or the other allowed arithmetic functions—all of which require factorizations) than it is to determine whether it's a perfect power to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

This has been solved on Facebook by Gjergji Zaimi with an idea that generalizes to the following criterion. Let $p$ be a prime, $n$ be a positive integer. Then $n$ is a $p$th power if and only if $d(n), ...., d(n^{p - 1})$ are all $1 \pmod{p}$. Then idea is that $d(n^m)$ being $1 \pmod{p}$ shows for all $k_j$ (multiplicities of primes dividing n), there are none which are $\equiv -m^{-1} \pmod{p}$. Indeed, otherwise we would have $mk_j + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, forcing $d(n^m) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. I suppose, in fact, you could just say that $d(n^m)$ are non-zero modulo $p$.

Comment: @BrianTung I've edited it to be MathJax'd.